# How to login in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made the login control from the visual studio 2008. Now am unable to make the users and their passwords. I also wanna know that how could i redirect it to the next page. As am a new to visual studio.

what is credentials SHA1?

thanxx

Answer (score 1):

To use the Login Control, you have to use an ASP.NET Membership-Provider in your website. To get you started, from Visual Studio, look at  Main Menu: Project, ASP.NET Configuration. This requires an SQL server, and maybe you have to create the database first with aspnet_regsql.exe

This probably isn't a full answer but it should get you started (searching).

Comment: i do agree with you am building a web application.....i which i added a login control....nw i want that if a user click to login my application the user shud be getting an access to next page.....

Comment: For a simple solution, make your own login form and see this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps required to use the Membership controls provided with ASP.NET. 
Firstly, you'll want to use the CreateUserWizard control, which will allow users to sign up to your site. Once they've completed this step, you can then use the login control. The built-in tools are quite restrictive on the information they take, but you can easily customise them. 
If you're new to ASP.NET, you might want to take a look at the introduction tutorials here:
http://www.asp.net/get-started/
If you just want Membership information, this video will teach you step-by-step:
http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-45.aspx

SHA-1 is a one way hash function which, on a very basic level, means that the person's password (in this case) is hashed and, therefore, cannot be retrieved. So, if a hacker got hold of your database, they would not be able to read the password as it would just be a bunch of letters and numbers. This is good for security. Downside is that you cannot recover the user's password since the function is one-way. Instead, you'll have to reset the person's password. You can use the PasswordRecovery control in ASP.NET to do this.